# Laravel Multi-Auth App with One Login Page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am creating a multi-auth app with Laravel,and I need all users to use one login page. How can I implement this feature using guards or middleware?

Comment: you mean each user to see different features / links when he/she logs in?

Comment: I mean all users whether admin or customer can use same  _/login_ route but after successful authentication they can be redirected to different routes.

Comment: just do it the traditional way,  php artisan make:auth it will generate the auth file which all users can login via the middleware. then you have to define roles and modules for the users when after successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that, you have to do this:

1. create a role table with roleID, roleName as fields
2. create modules table with modID, modName and route as fields
3. create assignModules table with assignmodID, roleID and modID as fields
4. create assignRole table with assignRoleID, roleID,usersID
5. create users table with usersID, etc.
6. you can create your route and save in module table
7. you can create your users role and save in role table
8. you can then assign module to role and save in assignmodule table
9. you can then assign role to users and save in assignrole table

this is just the logic. hope it helps